# Generate Doc pages from rows of spreadsheet data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I made a webpage via SquareSpace for a local sports camp, and the registration page saves all entries to a Google Spreadsheet in Drive. I would like to convert the document from this in the spreadsheet:

```
1. name      | currentgrade | parentorguardianname
2. Joe Smith |            7 | Mike Smith
3. Jenny Lee |            5 | Janet Lee
```

To this in a Google Doc

```
Name: Joe Smith
Grade: 7
Parent: Mike Smith

<page break>

Name: Jenny Lee
Grade: 6
Parent: Janet Lee
```

I need to rename the headers in the Doc so they're readable, and then use them on each row, with a page break in between each one. I accomplished this last year by copying the whole file to my desktop, converting it to excel, and using macro to convert to another sheet in the right format. I didn't write the macro myself (just edited the loop for each column), but this year I want to try to do this right so they could do it themselves going forward. I've never written any code like this, but I have some coding experience, so it'll be fun to learn.

Comment: In the spreadsheet this is how you can get the values in a range:https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows-numcolumns
And this is how you can insert information in a Doc: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph
Your question is too broad, you should work on the code and then ask if you have any specific issue. Check this documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I knew it was open ended, but I didn't know where to start. His gives me a good place to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pinoyyid is right, you've described a basic mail merge, and there are plenty of options for accomplishing what you ask.

However, it's also the sort of task that requires a tool you should have in your toolbox! Transposing rows of labeled data into *Things* is a common operation when dealing with Google Sheets, so this basic function can form the basis of many bigger things.

[image: spreadsheet]

```js
var docId = '--document id--';

/*
 * Replace content of a document with the current data in spreadsheet.
 * Each row of data will occupy one page in the document.
 * Header row from spreadsheet will provide data labels in document.
 */
function RowsToDoc() {
  // Get all sheet contents, remove header row
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues();
  var headers = data.splice(0, 1)[0];

  // Open document and prepare to write  
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.clear();

  // Loop over every row in sheet, adding pages to document
  for (var row=0; row<data.length; row++) {
    // Insert page break exept on first page
    if (row>0)
      body.appendPageBreak();
    // Loop over all columns, writing  "Data Label: Data"
    for (col = 0; col<headers.length; col++) {
      body.appendParagraph(headers[col] + ": " + data[row][col]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how to do this but creating a new document for each row?

Answer (score 0):

You've just described mail-merge. https://www.google.com/search?q=google+spreadsheet+mailmerge